# Can't show dataTables with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, get, render

I want to display data using dataTables. I have successfully get data, but it won't appear However the message is displayed

> "message": "HTTP request returned status code 500:\n<!DOCTYPE
> html>\n<html>\n <head>\n <meta name="robots"
> content="noindex,nofollow" / >\n <style>\n (truncated...)\n"

How can I solve this?

```
<script>
        $('#tap-role-manajemen').addClass('side-menu--active');
        const limit = 10
        const page = 1
        const column = ['nama', 'email', 'nomor_telp', 'roles', 'status'];
        const table = $('#table_roles').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            deferRender: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            dom: `
                <
                    <"util grid grid-cols-12 gap-6 mt-5"<"col-span-6"l>>
                    <tr>
                    <
                        <i><p>
                    >
                >`,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ route('getDataRoles') }}",
                type: 'GET',
                data: function(d) {
                    d.limit = d.length;
                    d.page = $('#table_roles').DataTable().page() + 1;
                    d.nama = d.columns[1].search.value;
                    d.email = d.columns[2].search.value;
                    d.nomor_telp = d.columns[3].search.value;
                    d.roles = d.columns[4].search.value;
                    d.status = d.columns[5].search.value;
                    //d.column = column[$('#table_roles').DataTable().order().length ? $('#table_roles').DataTable().order()[0][0] : 0];
                    d.order = $('#table_roles').DataTable().order().length ? $('#table_roles').DataTable().order()[0][1] : 'asc';
                    // console.log(d);
                },
                dataSrc: function(json) {
                    json.recordsTotal = json.data.total;
                    json.recordsFiltered = json.data.total;
                    return json.data.data;
                }
            },
            columns: [{
                    data: null,
                    render: function(data) {
                        return data;
                    },
                },
                {
                    data: 'nama'
                },
                {
                    data: 'email'
                },
                {
                    data: 'nomor_telp'
                },
                {
                    data: 'roles'
                },
                {
                    data: 'status'
                },
                {
                    data: null,
                    render: function() {
                        return `
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary btn-sm" aria-expanded="false" data-tw-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                                        stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                        <rect x="9" y="9" width="13" height="13" rx="2" ry="2"></rect>
                                        <path d="M5 15H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h9a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v1"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                                        stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                        <polyline points="6 9 12 15 18 9"></polyline>
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu w-40">
                                    <ul class="dropdown-content">
                                        <li> <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Edit Data</a> </li>
                                        <li> <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Hapus Data</a> </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        `;
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: null,
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        var updatedAt = moment(row.updated.at).format('MMM DD, YYYY @ HH:mm');
                        return updatedAt + ' by ' + row.updated.by;
                    }
                }
            ],
            order: [
                [7, 'asc']
            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                    orderable: false,
                    targets: [0, 6]
                },
                {
                    targets: '_all',
                    className: 'text-center'
                }
            ],
            initComplete: function() {
                this.api().columns([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).every(function(colIdx) {
                    const column = this;
                    const input = `
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        `;

                    $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty()).on('keyup', debounce(function() {
                        const val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                        column.search(val ? val : '', true, false).draw();
                    }, 500));
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Error 500 is a server error, but the error message you've posted is truncated so we can't see the actual problem. Can you find the Ajax request in your browser's developer console in the Network tab, then click the Response tab and it might show you a bit more information. If that doesn't work, find the error log for your server and get the error message from there. A final option is to install a debugger for your server-side code, which I would recommend generally, but it's a lot of work for a single error.

Comment: Side note (may or may not be related to your problem): You are using `serverSide: true`, so there is no need to explicitly send data such as `limit`, `page` and so on to the server. All the data needed by the server is automatically sent by [DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) whenever the user performs any action on the data table (sorting, searching, paging). You should use that data.